# Can we add/remove coding standards to CppCheck?

Tags: cppcheck

Can we add some of the coding standards which is not defined in Cppheck, or can we remove some of the coding standards defined in Cpppcheck which i does not want to check.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tailor the code standards by changing some configuration. But if you modify the source code of Cppcheck, you can do it.

Comment: more suits as comment

Comment: Are you sure?
I saw something permitting to do so:  
http://www.cs.kent.edu/~rothstei/spring_12/secprognotes/cppcheck_writing-rules-1.pdf